# Common Lisp: A predicate to tell if a list contains a nested list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I need a predicate that returns true if a list has a sublist, false otherwise.

I wrote a function to implement it (below). I wonder if such a predicate already exists?

```
(defun hasSublistp (lst)
    (cond ((null lst) nil)
          ((listp (first lst)) t)
          (t (hasSublistp (rest lst)))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
? (some #'listp '(1 2 3 4 5))
NIL
? (some #'listp '(1 2 (3 4) 4 5))
T
? (some #'listp '(1 2 (3 4) (4 7) 5))
T
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that there's a function *exactly* for this purpose, but what about:

```
(some #'listp my-list)
```

You can find more information about the higher order function `some` in the [hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_everyc.htm).